# Using line.replace in Python3 to renumber a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an output file from another part of code:

> 1434  CPM    3.958      20.716      72.669       94  1438  1465
> 1435  CPM    1.836      16.422      71.695       94  1441  1448
> 1436  CPM    2.634      17.182      67.015       94  1451  1455
> 1437  CPM    4.132      21.733      67.897       94  1458  1462
> 1438  CPB    3.349      19.474      72.781       93  1434  1439  1472
> 1439  CPA    3.118      18.784      74.036       92  1438  1440  1443
> 1440  CPA    2.552      17.612      73.778       92  1439  1441  1442
> 1441  CPB    2.378      17.502      72.348       93  1435  1440  1472
> 1442  CT3    2.158      16.567      74.855       27  1440
> 1443  CT2    3.485      19.307      75.452       26  1439  1444
> 1444  CT2    2.553      20.439      75.889       26  1443  1445
> 1445   CM    2.317      20.343      77.375       96  1444  1446  1447
> 1446  OH1    2.873      19.416      78.015       76  1445
> 1447   OM    1.582      21.197      77.930      105  1445
> 1448  CPB    1.923      16.208      70.337       93  1435  1449  1473
> 1449  CPA    1.600      14.991      69.612       92  1448  1450  1452
> 1450  CPA    1.816      15.216      68.315       92  1449  1451  1453
> 1451  CPB    2.285      16.572      68.185       93  1436  1450  1473
> 1452  CT3    1.091      13.691      70.273       27  1449
> 1453    C    1.653      14.262      67.103       95  1450  1454
> 1454    C    0.582      13.482      66.929       95  1453
> 1455  CPB    3.119      18.452      66.894       93  1436  1456  1474
> 1456  CPA    3.538      19.007      65.645       92  1455  1457  1459
> 1457  CPA    3.944      20.244      65.858       92  1456  1458  1460
> 1458  CPB    3.803      20.546      67.268       93  1437  1457  1474
> 1459  CT3    3.556      18.278      64.284       27  1456
> 1460    C    4.486      21.151      64.731       95  1457  1461
> 1461    C    4.266      22.469      64.758       95  1460
> 1462  CPB    4.362      21.866      69.256       93  1437  1463  1475
> 1463  CPA    5.109      22.925      69.918       92  1462  1464  1466
> 1464  CPA    5.050      22.612      71.413       92  1463  1465  1467
> 1465  CPB    4.294      21.373      71.505       93  1434  1464  1475
> 1466  CT3    5.789      24.129      69.239       27  1463
> 1467  CT2    5.685      23.426      72.579       26  1464  1468
> 1468  CT2    4.623      23.904      73.582       26  1467  1469
> 1469   CM    4.434      25.412      73.527       96  1468  1470  1471
> 1470  OH1    4.822      26.053      72.525       76  1469
> 1471   OM    3.847      25.982      74.474      105  1469
> 1472  NPH    2.870      18.669      71.752      100  1438  1441  1476
> 1473  NPH    2.335      17.156      69.426      100  1448  1451  1476
> 1474  NPH    3.284      19.422      67.889      100  1455  1458  1476
> 1475  NPH    3.914      20.981      70.226      100  1462  1465  1476
> 1476   FE    2.826      19.201      69.829      107   822  1472  1473  1474

What I need to do is renumber from 1434 to another number (e.g., 3168 in this case) and replace every instance of that number.Then go to the next number (1435) and change that and every instance of it to the next number in the sequence (3169). What I have written so-far is:

```
def renumber_xyz():
    file_name = "output1.txt"
    f1 = open(file_name, "rt")
    f2 = open("output2.txt", "wt")
    lines = f1.readlines()
    
    i = 1434
    j = 3168
    for line in lines:
        f2.write(line.replace(str(i), str(j)))
        
        i = int(i) + 1
        j = int(j) + 1
        
    f1.close()
    f2.close()  

renumber_xyz()
```

However, this only changes one instance of each number:

> 3168  CPM    3.958      20.716      72.669       94  1438  1465
> 3169  CPM    1.836      16.422      71.695       94  1441  1448
> 3170  CPM    2.634      17.182      67.015       94  1451  1455
> 3171  CPM    4.132      21.733      67.897       94  1458  1462
> 3172  CPB    3.349      19.474      72.781       93  1434  1439  1472
> 3173  CPA    3.118      18.784      74.036       92  1438  1440  1443
> 3174  CPA    2.552      17.612      73.778       92  1439  1441  1442
> 3175  CPB    2.378      17.502      72.348       93  1435  1440  1472
> 3176  CT3    2.158      16.567      74.855       27  1440
> 3177  CT2    3.485      19.307      75.452       26  1439  1444
> 3178  CT2    2.553      20.439      75.889       26  1443  1445
> 3179   CM    2.317      20.343      77.375       96  1444  1446  1447
> 3180  OH1    2.873      19.416      78.015       76  1445
> 3181   OM    1.582      21.197      77.930      105  1445
> 3182  CPB    1.923      16.208      70.337       93  1435  1449  1473
> 3183  CPA    1.600      14.991      69.612       92  1448  1450  1452
> 3184  CPA    1.816      15.216      68.315       92  1449  1451  1453
> 3185  CPB    2.285      16.572      68.185       93  1436  1450  1473
> 3186  CT3    1.091      13.691      70.273       27  1449
> 3187    C    1.653      14.262      67.103       95  1450  1454
> 3188    C    0.582      13.482      66.929       95  1453
> 3189  CPB    3.119      18.452      66.894       93  1436  1456  1474
> 3190  CPA    3.538      19.007      65.645       92  1455  1457  1459
> 3191  CPA    3.944      20.244      65.858       92  1456  1458  1460
> 3192  CPB    3.803      20.546      67.268       93  1437  1457  1474
> 3193  CT3    3.556      18.278      64.284       27  1456
> 3194    C    4.486      21.151      64.731       95  1457  1461
> 3195    C    4.266      22.469      64.758       95  1460
> 3196  CPB    4.362      21.866      69.256       93  1437  1463  1475
> 3197  CPA    5.109      22.925      69.918       92  1462  1464  1466
> 3198  CPA    5.050      22.612      71.413       92  1463  1465  1467
> 3199  CPB    4.294      21.373      71.505       93  1434  1464  1475
> 3200  CT3    5.789      24.129      69.239       27  1463
> 3201  CT2    5.685      23.426      72.579       26  1464  1468
> 3202  CT2    4.623      23.904      73.582       26  1467  1469
> 3203   CM    4.434      25.412      73.527       96  1468  1470  1471
> 3204  OH1    4.822      26.053      72.525       76  1469
> 3205   OM    3.847      25.982      74.474      105  1469
> 3206  NPH    2.870      18.669      71.752      100  1438  1441  1476
> 3207  NPH    2.335      17.156      69.426      100  1448  1451  1476
> 3208  NPH    3.284      19.422      67.889      100  1455  1458  1476
> 3209  NPH    3.914      20.981      70.226      100  1462  1465  1476
> 3210   FE    2.826      19.201      69.829      107   822  1472  1473  1474

Please excuse my amateur code, I'm no programmer! Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do the replacement line by line; you need to read the entire file into a string and do the replacements on that single string.

This code uses a regular expression to find all the numbers that start each line without assuming a start and end range.

```
import re


def renumber_xyz():
    # Use "with" context managers and the files will be closed at the end of the block
    with open("output1.txt", "rt") as f1, open("output2.txt", "wt") as f2:
        lines = f1.read()
        numbers = re.findall(r'^\d+', lines, re.M) # find numbers at start of a line
        replacement = 3168
        for number in numbers:
            lines = lines.replace(number, str(replacement))
            replacement += 1
        f2.write(lines)

renumber_xyz()
```

If you want to hard code the range of numbers:

```
def renumber_xyz():
    # Use "with" context managers and the files will be closed at the end of the block
    with open("output1.txt", "rt") as f1, open("output2.txt", "wt") as f2:
        lines = f1.read()
        replacement = 3168
        for number in range(1434, 1477):
            lines = lines.replace(str(number), str(replacement))
            replacement += 1
        f2.write(lines)

renumber_xyz()
```

output2.txt:

```
3168 CPM 3.958 20.716 72.669 94 3172 3199
3169 CPM 1.836 16.422 71.695 94 3175 3182
3170 CPM 2.634 17.182 67.015 94 3185 3189
3171 CPM 4.132 21.733 67.897 94 3192 3196
3172 CPB 3.349 19.474 72.781 93 3168 3173 3206
3173 CPA 3.118 18.784 74.036 92 3172 3174 3177
3174 CPA 2.552 17.612 73.778 92 3173 3175 3176
3175 CPB 2.378 17.502 72.348 93 3169 3174 3206
3176 CT3 2.158 16.567 74.855 27 3174
3177 CT2 3.485 19.307 75.452 26 3173 3178
3178 CT2 2.553 20.439 75.889 26 3177 3179
3179 CM 2.317 20.343 77.375 96 3178 3180 3181
3180 OH1 2.873 19.416 78.015 76 3179
3181 OM 1.582 21.197 77.930 105 3179
3182 CPB 1.923 16.208 70.337 93 3169 3183 3207
3183 CPA 1.600 14.991 69.612 92 3182 3184 3186
3184 CPA 1.816 15.216 68.315 92 3183 3185 3187
3185 CPB 2.285 16.572 68.185 93 3170 3184 3207
3186 CT3 1.091 13.691 70.273 27 3183
3187 C 1.653 14.262 67.103 95 3184 3188
3188 C 0.582 13.482 66.929 95 3187
3189 CPB 3.119 18.452 66.894 93 3170 3190 3208
3190 CPA 3.538 19.007 65.645 92 3189 3191 3193
3191 CPA 3.944 20.244 65.858 92 3190 3192 3194
3192 CPB 3.803 20.546 67.268 93 3171 3191 3208
3193 CT3 3.556 18.278 64.284 27 3190
3194 C 4.486 21.151 64.731 95 3191 3195
3195 C 4.266 22.469 64.758 95 3194
3196 CPB 4.362 21.866 69.256 93 3171 3197 3209
3197 CPA 5.109 22.925 69.918 92 3196 3198 3200
3198 CPA 5.050 22.612 71.413 92 3197 3199 3201
3199 CPB 4.294 21.373 71.505 93 3168 3198 3209
3200 CT3 5.789 24.129 69.239 27 3197
3201 CT2 5.685 23.426 72.579 26 3198 3202
3202 CT2 4.623 23.904 73.582 26 3201 3203
3203 CM 4.434 25.412 73.527 96 3202 3204 3205
3204 OH1 4.822 26.053 72.525 76 3203
3205 OM 3.847 25.982 74.474 105 3203
3206 NPH 2.870 18.669 71.752 100 3172 3175 3210
3207 NPH 2.335 17.156 69.426 100 3182 3185 3210
3208 NPH 3.284 19.422 67.889 100 3189 3192 3210
3209 NPH 3.914 20.981 70.226 100 3196 3199 3210
3210 FE 2.826 19.201 69.829 107 822 3206 3207 3208
```

Comment: Thank you! Hard coding in the numbers is actually ideal, because there is the possibility that for future data sets this renumbering will be in the middle of a series of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that for each line, it only attempts to replace one number with another and then moves onto the next line. However, each of your lines contains multiple unique numbers that need replacing, so instead of going line by line, try working with the entire body of text:

```
def renumber_xyz():
    file_name = "output1.txt"
    f1 = open(file_name, "rt")
    f2 = open("output2.txt", "wt")
    text = f1.read()

    # Iterate through each number i that needs replacing
    for i in range(1434, 1477):
      # Replace all occurrences in the entire file
      text = text.replace(str(i), str(i+1734))

    f2.write(text)
    
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

renumber_xyz()
```

This modified version of your code should do the job. Keep in mind that this won't work if the range of original numbers and the range of replacement numbers overlap.